# C# Entering 2 digit dates in date field defaults to 19 vs 20 on dates after 2020

Tags: c#, date, field

So a user enters 20 in a date field, the date fills to 2020.  Enter 21, and the date fills to 1921.  This happens for any dates after 2020.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The year where the two digit year "cuts" is in `Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax`.

More info on the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax

The value initially comes from the system's culture settings, but you can change it (or make your own culture)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example of `Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax`:

```
string dateString = "13 Jan 21"; //from user input
DateTime result;
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime.TryParse(dateString, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToLongDateString());

culture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099;

DateTime.TryParse(dateString, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToLongDateString());
```

This should gives:

```
13. januar 2021
13. januar 2021
```

Check the [source](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-parse-string-dates-with-a-two-digit-year-and-split-on-the-right-century-in-c#:%7E:text=Enter%20the%20Calendar.,29%20is%20interpreted%20as%202029.).